# How to implement a draw prize system where the prize has relative ratio of chance to obtain?

Tags: c++

for example, I have a list of prizes and, for each prize, a relative ratio constant that represents the chance to get it, as shown by the code below:

```
vector<pair<string,int> > prizeBox;
prizeBox.push_back(make_pair("toy car",100));
prizeBox.push_back(make_pair("football",50));
prizeBox.push_back(make_pair("book",50));
prizeBox.push_back(make_pair("cash 1000",10));
prizeBox.push_back(make_pair("cash 5000",5));
prizeBox.push_back(make_pair("free expensive lunch",2));
prizeBox.push_back(make_pair("free expensive dinner",2));
prizeBox.push_back(make_pair("special big price",1));
```

In the code above, "toy car" has a 100/(100+50+50+10+5+2+2+1) chance to be obtained. I know rand() could be used to get a random number, but how do I use it in this case?

(Also I don't believe I need to have a new vector that adds 100 "toy car", 50 "football" and so on to do that...)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of creating your own distribution, you can easily use `std::discrete_distribution` for this:

```
int main()
{
    //create vector and fill it
    std::vector<std::tuple<std::string,int> > prizeBox { {"toy car",100}, {"football",50}, {"book",50}, {"cash 1000",10} };

    //create a vector of the second entries of vector-elements of prizeBox
    std::vector<int> chance;
    std::transform(std::begin(prizeBox), std::end(prizeBox), std::back_inserter(chance), [](auto p){return std::get<1>(p);});

    //set up the distribution and the random number generator
    auto dist = std::discrete_distribution<int>(std::begin(chance), std::end(chance));
    std::mt19937_64 rng;

    //draws ten time from the prize box
    for(int i=0;i<10;++i)
    {
        std::cout<<std::get<0>(prizeBox[dist(rng)])<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/25599235e049cf3a)

EDIT: The only problem with the above solution is the copy of the tuple's first entries into a new vector. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34198818/c-iterate-over-vector-of-objects-and-apply-stl-algorithms-to-member-variables) you can find approaches to work directly on the tuple-vector.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to index with weigthed probability , I guess I would stuff like this

```
srand(time(NULL));

vector<pair<string,int> > prizeBox; 

int total = 100+50+50+10+5+2+2+1;

int random = rand()%(total);
if(random < 100){
    // acces to prizeBox[0];
}
else if(random < 150){
    //acces to prizeBox[1];
}
else if (random < 200)
    // and so on
```

PS : You can use initializer list to init your tab by doing (it's prettier than several push_back

```
    vector<pair<string,int> > prizeBox  = { {"toy car",100} , {"football",50} };
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that draws a random prize based on the chances you wanted. The idea is to first iterate trough the vector and get the sum of the chances. Then, generate a random number from 1 to that sum and iterate again, subtracting the current chance from the random number. When the random number gets smaller than the current chance, you have your sorted prize. The code below shows the implementation.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

string drawPrize (vector<pair<string, int> > prizeBox) {
    //iterate through vector to get the sum of the weigths.
    int total = 0;
    for (vector<pair<string,int> >::iterator it = prizeBox.begin() ; it != prizeBox.end(); ++it)
        total += it->second;

    // getting a random number
    srand(time(NULL));
    int r = rand() % total + 1; // a number from 1 to total

    // finding the prize
    vector<pair<string,int> >::iterator it = prizeBox.begin();
    while (r > it->second && it != prizeBox.end()) {
        r -= it->second;
        it++;
    }

    // returning the sorted prize
    return it->first;
}
```