# C++ iterate over vector of objects and apply STL algorithms to member variables

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

What again is the quick way to iterate over a vector of custom objects but access only a single member in order to apply general STL-algorithms?

```
struct Foo
{
    std::string a;
    double b = 1.0;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Foo> fooVector(20);

    // iterate over all members b -- as if we were iterating over a std::vector<double>
    std::discrete_distribution<int> dist(/*??*/, /*??*/);
}
```

With "quick" I mean

- no custom iterator -- or only a very lightweight one (--a few lines of code, no boost `iterator_facade`, etc.),
- no modification of the dereferencing operator (--not that quick).

Comment: [`std::for_each`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you don't want to use the custom binary operation. Which algorithms specifically would you want to use which don't allow the provision of a function to use?

Comment: @TartanLlama: the `std::discrete_distribution` constructor which takes iterators ... thought that is too distracting cause unknown

Comment: Is it `std::discrete_distribution<double>` instead ?

Comment: @Caduchon: no, the `int` specifies the return type. The problem is the constructor doesn't take iterators returning `Foo const&` upon dereferentation. It expects scalar types like `double`.

Comment: @davidhigh Not sure how you would do it without a custom iterator/custom `operator*()`... I implemented a simple `LightIterator` [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c042d8fbe979ba89). Could that be an acceptable compromise for your application ?

Comment: @865719: good! post that please (the overloading of `operator*` for `LightweightIterator` is of course acceptable -- but not that of `Foo`).

Comment: @davidhigh I've edited the code in order to work around the problem mentioned by TartanLlama. The result is obviously less concise but it gets the job done while being generic enough :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution mentioned in my comment:

```
struct LightIterator : public std::vector<Foo>::iterator
{
    LightIterator(std::vector<Foo>::iterator it) : std::vector<Foo>::iterator(it) {}
    double& operator*() { return std::vector<Foo>::iterator::operator*().b; }
};
```

Which you can use like this:

<kbd>[**Run It Online**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c042d8fbe979ba89)</kbd>

```
std::accumulate(LightIterator{fooVector.begin()},
                LightIterator{fooVector.end()},
                0.0);
```

**EDIT**: @TartanLlama is right about the issue related to the actual type of `std::vector<Foo>::iterator`.

As an attempt to have a more generic solution, I suggest that you define a wrapper iterator class for when `std::vector<Foo>::iterator` is a raw pointer. Something like:

*(notice that I'm now allowing arbitrary attributes to be selected. More on that later)*

```
template <
    typename PointerType,
    typename ItemType,
    typename AttributeType
>
struct LightIterator_FromPointer : public std::iterator<std::input_iterator_tag,
                                                        std::remove_pointer_t<PointerType>>
{
    PointerType it;
    AttributeType ItemType::* pointerToAttribute;
    LightIterator_FromPointer(PointerType it_, AttributeType ItemType::* pointerToAttribute_)
    : it(it_)
    , pointerToAttribute(pointerToAttribute_)
    {}

    AttributeType& operator*() { return it->*pointerToAttribute; }
    AttributeType* operator->() { return it; }

    // input iterator boilerplate: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/InputIterator
    using this_t = LightIterator_FromPointer<PointerType, ItemType, AttributeType>;  // less typing...
    LightIterator_FromPointer(const this_t& other) : it(other.it) {}
    bool operator!=(const this_t& other) const { return it != other.it; }
    this_t& operator++() { ++it; return *this; }
    this_t operator++(const int) { return {it++}; }
};
```

While still keeping the original "minimal" light iterator for when `std::vector<Foo>::iterator` is actually a class:

```
template <
    typename IteratorType,
    typename ItemType,
    typename AttributeType
>
struct LightIterator_FromClass : public IteratorType
{
    AttributeType ItemType::* pointerToAttribute;
    LightIterator_FromClass(IteratorType it_, AttributeType ItemType::* pointerToAttribute_)
    : IteratorType(it_)
    , pointerToAttribute(pointerToAttribute_)
    {}
    AttributeType& operator*() { return IteratorType::operator*().*pointerToAttribute; }
};
```

Finally, in order to abstract the details of the light iterator type that should be used on the call site, you can define a `make_iterator()` function that takes care of everything:

```
template <
    typename IteratorType,
    typename ItemType,
    typename AttributeType
>
typename std::conditional<std::is_pointer<IteratorType>::value,
    LightIterator_FromPointer<IteratorType, ItemType, AttributeType>,
    LightIterator_FromClass<IteratorType, ItemType, AttributeType>
>::type
make_iterator(IteratorType it, AttributeType ItemType::* pointerToAttribute)
{
    return typename std::conditional<std::is_pointer<IteratorType>::value,
        LightIterator_FromPointer<IteratorType, ItemType, AttributeType>,
        LightIterator_FromClass<IteratorType, ItemType, AttributeType>
    >::type(it, pointerToAttribute);
}
```

The result is a simple calling syntax which *(bonus)* allows for selecting any attribute, not only `Foo::b`.

<kbd>[**Run It Online**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3d53053df9b10e4b)</kbd>

```
// light iterator from an actual iterator "class"
{
    std::vector<Foo> fooVector(20);

    double acc = std::accumulate(make_iterator(fooVector.begin(), &Foo::b),
                                 make_iterator(fooVector.end(),  &Foo::b),
                                 0.0);
    cout << acc << endl;
}

// light iterator from a "pointer" iterator
{
    std::array<Foo, 20> fooVector;

    double acc = std::accumulate(make_iterator(fooVector.begin(), &Foo::b),
                                 make_iterator(fooVector.end(), &Foo::b),
                                 0.0);
    cout << acc << endl;
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is portable. `std::vector<Foo>::iterator` could just be a pointer, so inheriting from it would be a compile-time error. You'd be better off having the iterator as a member and forwarding all the necessary operators to the internal iterator.

Comment: @TartanLlama You're right! :) I've just adapted the code to take that into account.

Answer (score 2):

The constructor of `std::discrete_distribution<...>` doesn't support any explicit way to project values (like a function object optionally applied to transform the result of `*it` before being used). As a result I think there are three basic approaches:

1. Use an intermediate `std::vector<double>` to obtain a range whose iterators yield doubles:

   ```
   std::vector<double> tmp; // reserve() as desired
   std::transform(fooVector.begin(), fooVector.end(),
                  std::back_inserter(tmp),
                  [](Foo const& f){ return f.b; });
   std::discrete_distribution<int> d(tmp.begin(), tmp.end());
   ```
2. It *may* viable to use a conversion operator on `Foo` to convert into a `double`:

   ```
   class Foo {
       // ...
       operator double() const { return this->b; }
   };
   // ...
   std::discrete_distribution<int> d(fooVector.begin(), fooVector.end());
   ```
3. Create a wrapper for the iterator and use that. It doesn't need anything fancy but putting together a simple input iterators is still comparatively involved:

   ```
   template <typename InIt>
   class project_iterator {
       InIt it;
   public:
       explicit project_iterator(InIt it): it(it) {}
       double operator*() const { return *this->it; }
       project_iterator& operator++() { ++this->it; return *this; }
       project_iterator  operator++(int) {
           project_iterator rc(*this);
           this->operator++();
           return *this;
       }
       bool operator==(project_iterator const& other) const {
           return this->it == other.it;
       }
       bool operator!=(project_iterator const& other) const {
           return !(*this == other);
       }
   };
   template <typename It>
   project_iterator<It> project(It it) {
       return project_iterator<It>(it);
   }
   namespace std {
       template <typename It>
       class iterator_traits<project_iterator<It> {
       public:
           typedef typename std::iterator_traits<It>::difference_type difference_type;
           typedef double value_type;
           typedef double& reference;
           typedef double* pointer;
           typedef std::input_iterator_tag iterator_category;
       }
   }
   // ...
   std::discrete_distribution<int> d(project(fooVector.begin()), project(fooVector.end());
   ```

There are, obviously, variation on these approaches but I don't think there is anything else which can be done cleverly. What is missing is essentially a general approach to have projections with sequences (I'm normally referring to them as [property maps](https://github.com/dietmarkuehl/kuhllib/wiki/STL-2.0)).